# How to assign property in PageModel (by button) for form, maintaining selected page layout [ASP.NET/Razor Page]

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, edit, razor-pages

My project has page to manage armors. So far page allows user to show table from DB, create new armor and delete. Unfortunately, I was unable to implement editing/updating. 
When user first open page what is seen is table with items and each item have 2 buttons (edit and delete). Above table lays button making DIV containing table disappear and showing DIV containing form. Edit button does this same. This is handled by JavaScript. 
I want to use this same form to update armors. But to do it, first need to assign selected armor to Armor property in PageModel. So far, I was able to do it with IActionResult OnPost method, but page then is reloaded losing all my effort. When I tried to return Page() then my page was reloaded with empty table, if I use RedirectToPage(“PageName”) then I still lose selected item and by default table is shown, not the form with selected armor data. How can I do it? It is possible without using additional JavaScript but OnPost metod/s? If not, what can I change and how? 
I am using asp.net core 3.1, Entity Framework and Razor Pages. 
GitHub: https://github.com/Mlorism/LastTemple/tree/master/LastTemple/Pages/Manage

CSHTML:

```
<div class="col-7 pl-5 pr-5">
    <div id="armourTable" class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-light mb-2" onclick="ToggleColumn(1)">Stwórz pancerz</button>
        <table class="table text-light text-center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Id</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nazwa</th>
                    <th scope="col">Odp. fiz.</th>
                    <th scope="col">Odp. mag.</th>
                    <th scope="col"></th>                     
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Armors)
                {
                    <tr id="tr-@item.Id">
                        <th scope="row">@item.Id</th>                 
                        <td>@item.Name</td>
                        <td>@item.DamageResistance</td>
                        <td>@item.MagicResistance</td>
                        <td><form method="post"><button class="btn btn-outline-warning" type="submit" onclick="Edit(@item.Id)" asp-page-handler="LoadArmor" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edytuj</button></form></td>
                        <td><form method="post"><button class="btn btn-outline-warning" type="submit" asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Usuń</button></form></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="armourForm" class="p-5">
        <form id="manipulateArmor" method="post" onreset="resetSliders()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nazwa</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control bg-secondary text-light" minlength="5" maxlength="20" required="required" asp-for="Armor.Name" />
                <small>Długość od 5 do 20 znaków</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Odporność na obrażenia</label>
                <input id="physical" class="mySlider" type="range" value="10" min="0" max="100" step="5" asp-for="Armor.DamageResistance" />
                <output>10</output>
            </div>
            <div class="form-text">
                <label>Odporność na magię</label>
                <input id="magic" class="mySlider" type="range" value="10" min="0" max="50" step="5" asp-for="Armor.MagicResistance" />
                <output>10</output>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Create" class="btn btn-outline-success m-2">Zapisz</button>
                <button id="resetBtn" type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-warning m-2">Resetuj</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger m-2" onclick="ToggleColumn(0)">Anuluj</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

PageModel cs:

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _ctx;

    public ArmourModel(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Armor Armor { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public IEnumerable<Armor> Armors { get; set; }
    
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Armors = new GetArmors(_ctx).Get();                 
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostCreateAsync()
    {
        await new CreateArmor(_ctx).Create(Armor);          
            
        return RedirectToPage("Armor");
    }

    public IActionResult OnPostLoadArmor(int id)
    {
        Armor item = _ctx.Armors.Find(id);

        if (item == null)
        {
            RedirectToPage("Armor");
        }

        Armor.Id = item.Id;
        Armor.Name = item.Name;
        Armor.DamageResistance = item.DamageResistance;
        Armor.MagicResistance = item.MagicResistance;

        return RedirectToPage("Armor");
    }
```

JS:

```
function ToggleColumn(type) {
        var armourTable = document.getElementById("armourTable");
        var armourForm = document.getElementById("armourForm");
        var resetBtn = document.getElementById("resetBtn");

        if (type == 0) {
            armourTable.style.display = "block";
            armourForm.style.display = "none";
            resetBtn.style.display = "inline-block";                
        }

        else {   
                armourForm.style.display = "block";
                armourTable.style.display = "none";                    
                setSlider("physical");
                setSlider("magic");
                
            if (type == 2) {
                    resetBtn.style.display = "none";
            }                    
        }
    } // ToggleColumn()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified it and also add some js codes to implement your needs, you can refer to the below codes:

**Armor.cshtml**

```
@page
@model LastTemple.Pages.Create.ArmourModel
@{ }
<p class="text-center font-weight-bold mb-2">Zarządzaj pancerzami</p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-5 p-1">
        <img src="~/img/armor.png" class="img-thumbnail-dark" />
    </div>


    <div class="col-7 pl-5 pr-5">
        <div id="armourTable" class="text-center">

            <button class="btn btn-outline-light mb-2" onclick="ToggleColumn(1)">Stwórz pancerz</button>

            <table class="table text-light text-center">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nazwa</th>
                        <th scope="col">Odp. fiz.</th>
                        <th scope="col">Odp. mag.</th>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    @foreach (var item in Model.Armors)
                    {
        <tr id="tr-@item.Id">
            <th scope="row">@item.Id</th>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>@item.DamageResistance</td>
            <td>@item.MagicResistance</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-outline-warning" name="edit" type="submit" onclick="ToggleColumn(2)">Edytuj</button></td>
            <td><form method="post"><button class="btn btn-outline-warning" type="submit" asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Usuń</button></form></td>
        </tr>
}

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div id="armourForm" style="display:none" class="p-5">
            <form id="manipulateArmor" method="post" onreset="resetSliders()">
                <input type="hidden" id="id" asp-for="Armor.Id" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nazwa</label>
                    <input type="text" id="nazwa" class="form-control bg-secondary text-light" minlength="5" maxlength="20" required="required" asp-for="Armor.Name" />
                    <small>Długość od 5 do 20 znaków</small>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Odporność na obrażenia</label>
                    <input id="physical" class="mySlider" type="range" value="10" min="0" max="100" step="5" asp-for="Armor.DamageResistance" />
                    <output>10</output>
                </div>

                <div class="form-text">
                    <label>Odporność na magię</label>
                    <input id="magic" class="mySlider" type="range" value="10" min="0" max="50" step="5" asp-for="Armor.MagicResistance" />
                    <output>10</output>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center">
                    <button id="createBtn" type="submit" asp-page-handler="Create" class="btn btn-outline-success m-2">Zapisz</button>
                    <button id="editBtn" type="submit" asp-page-handler="Update" class="btn btn-outline-success m-2">Edytować</button>
                    <button id="resetBtn" type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-warning m-2">Resetuj</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger m-2" onclick="ToggleColumn(0)">Anuluj</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>


    </div>

    @section scripts{
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var form = document.getElementById("manipulateArmor");
            loadSettings();
            document.getElementById("physical").oninput = function () { setSlider("physical"); }
            document.getElementById("magic").oninput = function () { setSlider("magic"); }

            function loadSettings() {
                setSlider("physical");
                setSlider("magic");
                ToggleColumn(0);
            }

            function resetSliders() {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(function (timestamp) {
                    setSlider("physical");
                    setSlider("magic");
                })
            }

            function setSlider(type) {
                var slider = document.getElementById(type)
            
                var value = (slider.value - slider.min) / (slider.max - slider.min) * 100

                if (slider == null) {
                    alert("slider is null");
                }

                if (type == "physical") {
                    slider.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, #FF6B6B 0%, #FF0000 ' + value + '%, #000 ' + value + '%, black 100%)'
                }

                else {
                    slider.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, #0000FF 0%, #6600CC ' + value + '%, #000 ' + value + '%, black 100%)'
                }
                slider.nextElementSibling.value = slider.value
            };

        
            function ToggleColumn(type) {
                var armourTable = document.getElementById("armourTable");
                var armourForm = document.getElementById("armourForm");
                var resetBtn = document.getElementById("resetBtn");
                var createBtn = document.getElementById("createBtn");
                var editBtn = document.getElementById("editBtn");

                if (type == 0) {
                    armourTable.style.display = "block";
                    armourForm.style.display = "none";
                    editBtn.style.display = "none";
                    resetBtn.style.display = "inline-block";
                }
                else {
                    armourForm.style.display = "block";
                    armourTable.style.display = "none";
                    setSlider("physical");
                    setSlider("magic");
                    if (type == 2) {
                        var x = event.srcElement.parentElement.parentElement;
                        var id = x.children[0].innerHTML;
                        var name = x.children[1].innerHTML;
                        $("#id").val(id);
                        $("#nazwa").val(name);
                        editBtn.style.display ="inline-block"
                        resetBtn.style.display = "none";
                        createBtn.style.display = "none";
                    
                    } else {
                        editBtn.style.display = "none";
                        resetBtn.style.display = "inline-block";
                        createBtn.style.display = "inline-block";
                    }
                }
            } 
        </script>
    }
</div>
```

**Update function:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUpdateAsync()
{
    var target = _ctx.Armors.Find(Armor.Id);
    if (target == null)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("Armor");
    }
    target.Name = Armor.Name;
    target.DamageResistance = Armor.DamageResistance;
    target.MagicResistance = Armor.MagicResistance;

    await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToPage("Armor");
}
```

**Result:**

[image]